# Mobile app for Windows Phone

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app

I use the Android app regularly for browsing, and recently started logging on in order to get my Bugadroid hat in Winter Bash '14

But when I tried to search on the Windows Phone store (yes, on my Windows Phone) there are no official Stack Overflow apps available.

Is it possible to port the Android/ios app to WP8.1?

Comment: See [Official Stack Exchange application for Windows Phone OS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225624/164403) on the Overmeta.

Comment: [This has been discussed on Meta Stack Exchange.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225624/official-stack-exchange-application-for-windows-phone-os) While Stack Exchange hasn't made an "official" statement in a while, their last statement was that they were focusing on Android and iOS only for now, likely because of their much larger market share.